# PouchDB error is undefined

Tags: webpack, pouchdb

I am using PouchDB 5.6.0 to sync to a local CouchDb on my Server.

It worked before, but now it doesnt work anymore to replicate the databases.

The code in my bundle.js is as follows:

```
    const db = new PouchDB("actions");
    const remoteDatabase = new PouchDB(url);
    $("#syncAgain").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    console.log("disable");
    yield db.sync(remoteDatabase, {
        timeout: 2000
    }).on('change', function (info) {
        console.log("change");
    }).on('paused', function (err) {
        console.log("pause \n: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }).on('active', function () {
        console.log("active");
    }).on('denied', function (err) {
        console.log("denied");
    }).on('complete', function (info) {
        console.log("complete");
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("error \n: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
```

and the result in the browser is:

```
active
pause 
: undefined
complete
```

I can ping the remoteDatabase and the database exists, so the remoteDatabase is not wrong